# MKMapView memory leak in iOS 10

Tags: swift, mkmapview, ios10

I have integrated MKMapView in my project but when i pop that controller it not able to free the Memory .I am facing this issue in iOS 10 only I have tested in iOS 9 it's working fine.

I tried to free the memory with below code but it's not working.

```
let overlays = self.mapView.overlays
self.mapView.removeOverlays(overlays)
self.mapView.mapType = MKMapType.standard
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = false        
self.mapView.removeAnnotations(self.containerView.mapView.annotations)
self.mapView.delegate = nil
self.mapView.removeFromSuperview()
self.mapView = nil
```

Comment: can you share all your viewController code?